# Betting Smart contract using Token (Bep-20/erc20) instead of ether/bnb?

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, tokens

This is my betting contract using eth/bnb, how can I change eth/bnb to token as their betting payment
https://github.com/laronlineworld/BettingCOD/blob/main/BettingCOD.sol

Code for Betting

```
function bet(uint8 _teamSelected) public payable {
  require(bettingActive);
  //The first require is used to check if the player already exist
  require(!checkPlayerExists(msg.sender));
  //The second one is used to see if the value sended by the player is
  //Higher than the minimum value
  require(msg.value >= minimumBet);

  //We set the player informations : amount of the bet and selected team
  playerInfo[msg.sender].amountBet = msg.value;
  playerInfo[msg.sender].teamSelected = _teamSelected;

  //then we add the address of the player to the players array
  players.push(msg.sender);

  //at the end, we increment the stakes of the team selected with the player bet
  if ( _teamSelected == 1){
      totalBetsOne += msg.value;
  }
  else{
      totalBetsTwo += msg.value;
  }
}
```

Code for Distribution of prize

```
// Generates a number between 1 and 10 that will be the winner
function distributePrizes(uint16 teamWinner) public onlyOwner {
  require(bettingActive == false);
  address[1000] memory winners;
  //We have to create a temporary in memory array with fixed size
  //Let's choose 1000
  uint256 count = 0; // This is the count for the array of winners
  uint256 LoserBet = 0; //This will take the value of all losers bet
  uint256 WinnerBet = 0; //This will take the value of all winners bet

  //We loop through the player array to check who selected the winner team
  for(uint256 i = 0; i < players.length; i++){
     address playerAddress = players[i];

     //If the player selected the winner team
     //We add his address to the winners array
     if(playerInfo[playerAddress].teamSelected == teamWinner){
        winners[count] = playerAddress;
        count++;
     }
  }

  //We define which bet sum is the Loser one and which one is the winner
  if ( teamWinner == 1){
     LoserBet = totalBetsTwo;
     WinnerBet = totalBetsOne;
  }
  else{
      LoserBet = totalBetsOne;
      WinnerBet = totalBetsTwo;
  }


  //We loop through the array of winners, to give ethers to the winners
  for(uint256 j = 0; j < count; j++){
      // Check that the address in this fixed array is not empty
     if(winners[j] != address(0))
        address add = winners[j];
        uint256 bet = playerInfo[add].amountBet;
        //Transfer the money to the user
        winners[j].transfer(    (bet*(10000+(LoserBet*devFee /WinnerBet)))/10000 );
  }
  delete playerInfo[playerAddress]; // Delete all the players
  players.length = 0; // Delete all the players array
  LoserBet = 0; //reinitialize the bets
  WinnerBet = 0;
  totalBetsOne = 0;
  totalBetsTwo = 0;
}
```

How Can I change the eth/bnb to token as a betting payment and prize?
Any guide? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code, I can tell you it should be written like this, but I can't guarantee it will work perfectly, God bless you!

It's important to know that before you bet, before the `transferFrom()` call, you need to call `approval()` on the front end to approve the use of the user's token for your contract!

In addition, only your transfer code was modified when the prize was sent, other codes were not modified. I cannot guarantee your other codes.

```
 function bet(uint8 _teamSelected,uint256 amount) public  {
            require(bettingActive);
            //The first require is used to check if the player already exist
            require(!checkPlayerExists(msg.sender));
            //The second one is used to see if the value sended by the player is
            //Higher than the minimum value
            require(amount >= minimumBet);
    
    
            //To roll in the Token, this line of code is executed on the condition that the user has approved a contract to use his Token
            //IERC20 is Token
            IERC20.transferFrom(msg.sender,address(this),amount);
    
            //We set the player informations : amount of the bet and selected team
            playerInfo[msg.sender].amountBet = amount;
            playerInfo[msg.sender].teamSelected = _teamSelected;
    
            //then we add the address of the player to the players array
            players.push(msg.sender);
    
            //at the end, we increment the stakes of the team selected with the player bet
            if ( _teamSelected == 1){
                totalBetsOne += amount;
            }
            else{
                totalBetsTwo += amount;
            }
        }
```

and

```
  // Generates a number between 1 and 10 that will be the winner
    function distributePrizes(uint16 teamWinner) public onlyOwner {
        require(bettingActive == false);
        address[1000] memory winners;
        //We have to create a temporary in memory array with fixed size
        //Let's choose 1000
        uint256 count = 0; // This is the count for the array of winners
        uint256 LoserBet = 0; //This will take the value of all losers bet
        uint256 WinnerBet = 0; //This will take the value of all winners bet

        //We loop through the player array to check who selected the winner team
        for(uint256 i = 0; i < players.length; i++){
            address playerAddress = players[i];

            //If the player selected the winner team
            //We add his address to the winners array
            if(playerInfo[playerAddress].teamSelected == teamWinner){
                winners[count] = playerAddress;
                count++;
            }
        }

        //We define which bet sum is the Loser one and which one is the winner
        if ( teamWinner == 1){
            LoserBet = totalBetsTwo;
            WinnerBet = totalBetsOne;
        }
        else{
            LoserBet = totalBetsOne;
            WinnerBet = totalBetsTwo;
        }


        //We loop through the array of winners, to give ethers to the winners
        for(uint256 j = 0; j < count; j++){
            // Check that the address in this fixed array is not empty
            if(winners[j] != address(0))
                address add = winners[j];
            uint256 bet = playerInfo[add].amountBet;
            //Transfer the money to the user
//            winners[j].transfer(    (bet*(10000+(LoserBet*devFee /WinnerBet)))/10000 );

            IERC20.transfer(winners[j],  (bet*(10000+(LoserBet*devFee /WinnerBet)))/10000 )

        }
        delete playerInfo[playerAddress]; // Delete all the players
        players.length = 0; // Delete all the players array
        LoserBet = 0; //reinitialize the bets
        WinnerBet = 0;
        totalBetsOne = 0;
        totalBetsTwo = 0;
    }
```

Comment: If you have any other questions, you can ask me

Comment: I having a problem on distribution of rewards and betting, only 1 address can bet and It has an error on distribution of prize " { "code": 3, "message": "execution reverted: SafeMath: subtraction overflow", "data":"

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with your code ,You need to provide more information 

Comment: My error are "Fail with error 'ERC20: transfer amount exceeds allowance'" and Fail with error 'SafeMath: subtraction overflow'

Comment: It may be that the contract has not been approved for enough money, or the user's balance is not enough, and you should check them.

Comment: In addition, I have already emphasized that you need to approve the contract to use the user token. This step cannot be performed inside the contract. You must call the approval function outside the contract, such as using Web3JS to execute the contract's approval function, and let the user confirm in the wallet.

Comment: You should understand that asking the user to approve the token amount on the front end is what all DeFi projects do, and there is really no better way to do it, but to reduce the number of approvals, set a Max the first time so that no additional approvals are required next time

Comment: I will try to execute the contract with frontend so that I can compare the issue, Thank you